# Response not returning result

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#

Hi I m using FuelSDK for Exact Target API integration.
When I m running code of ET_SentEvent then it return proper value.
but again when i m running same code it return zero result.

after 30 min or more like that when i run same code the its return #238 result.
but again not.

Is there are any restriction to send multiple  request on  Exacttarget srever ?
or any time limit.

please reply

EDIT:  ADDING CODE

```
partial class Tester { static void TestET_SentEvent() {

    DateTime filterDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 15, 13, 0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("--- Testing SentEvent ---");
    ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client();

    Console.WriteLine("Retrieve Filtered SentEvents with GetMoreResults");
    ET_SentEvent oe = new ET_SentEvent();
    oe.AuthStub = myclient;
    oe.SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "EventDate", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.greaterThan, DateValue = new DateTime[] { filterDate } };
    oe.Props = new string[] { "SendID", "SubscriberKey", "EventDate", "Client.ID", "EventType", "BatchID", "TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID", "PartnerKey" };
    GetReturn oeGet = oe.Get();

    Console.WriteLine("Get Status: " + oeGet.Status.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + oeGet.Message.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Code: " + oeGet.Code.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Results Length: " + oeGet.Results.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("MoreResults: " + oeGet.MoreResults.ToString());
    // Since this could potentially return a large number of results, we do not want to print the results
    foreach (ET_SentEvent SentEvent in oeGet.Results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SubscriberKey: " + SentEvent.SubscriberKey + ", EventDate: " + SentEvent.EventDate.ToString());
    }

    while (oeGet.MoreResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Continue Retrieve Filtered SentEvents with GetMoreResults");
        oeGet = oe.GetMoreResults();
        Console.WriteLine("Get Status: " + oeGet.Status.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + oeGet.Message.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Code: " + oeGet.Code.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Results Length: " + oeGet.Results.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("MoreResults: " + oeGet.MoreResults.ToString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please post some code samples and we'll have a look.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, and the number of records returned is erratic too, any ideas?